# Perforce P4Report plugin Truncates text

Tags: odbc, perforce

I gave this plugin (P4Report) a go as recommended here and it works beautifully, I set up ODBC Data Sources properly and its bringing all the right fields across.

My main problem seems to be it not properly importing a "Description" string field and shortening it to less than 50 characters making the whole table pointless as the change descriptions are not being shown fully.

Tried importing into both Access and Excel 2013, both have the same issue.
Doubled checked and got my colleague to look with me that I had setup everything correctly and still wont fully show the description column.

Would be really nice having this working to help create patch notes.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you set up your query, under "changes" add "p4options". For p4options, add equals "longdesc" to add the long description.

The query will take longer to load, but it will pull over a longer description.

Comment: Where are you seeing this option?, I see it neither in "ODBC Data Sources (64-bit)" when creating the query nor in Microsoft Query when bringing it into Excel?

Comment: I'm using Excel 2007. 

If I go to Data-->From Other Sources-->From Microsoft Query and select Perforce, it brings up the Query Wizard. I unzip "changes" and choose the columns I want, and include "p4options". Select Next to specify which rows to include.For "p4options" I select "equals" and enter (manually) "longdesc" in the right side entry field. From there, finish the wizard.